# filename-generator-expression not available in spring-integration-file.xsd

Tags: maven, spring-integration

We have the following in our Spring Integration context file:

```
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="file:/output"
     filename-generator-expression="headers['id']+'.xml'" />
```

IntelliJ complains that "`Attribute filename-generator-expression is not allowed here`".

The spring-integration-file-2.0.xsd online at `https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/72302166/` shows that the attribute filename-generator-expression is indeed in the schema.

However, in IntelliJ, under External Libraries, within the `spring-integration-file-2.0.3-RELEASE` jar which has been downloaded, the spring-integration-file-2.0.xsd included there does **NOT** include the attribute.

Our pom.xml file declares dependencies on: `spring-integration-core` and `spring-integration-jms` using version: `Spring Integration: 4.1.0-RELEASE`. There is no direct dependency on spring-integration-file.

Our Spring Integration context file has the following declarations:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Running `mvn dependency:tree` should reveal where this dependency comes from.

Answer (score 0):

It was [added in 2.0.4](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-1856).

You need to add `spring-integtation-file` to to your pom to use the `<file: .../`> namespace and it **must** be the same version as `spring-integration-core` (4.1.0). I have no idea why your intellij has that old jar.